# Is there block scope really in JavaScript (as a first-class language concept)?

Tags: javascript

As we know, traditionally JS has been lacking block scope. As we know JS has had only function scope up until recently.

In recent versions of JS though, we can have `let` and `const` variables which are visible only in the scope where they are defined.

But... deep down... how is this done/implemented really? Is there really now in the language **a first-class notion of block scope in JS**, or is the block scope thing just some simulation to make certain variables visible only in the block where they are defined?

I mean is block scope in recent JS versions **a first-class thing**, just like function scope is, or is block scope just some sort of simulation while we actually still have just the old good function scope?

Comment: What would it mean practically for it to be a first-class notion as opposed to it being simulated?

Comment: The language defines a syntax and behaviour for it. An engine *may* implement it any way it chooses, as long as it exhibits the defined characteristics. Compilers may compile it down to other primitives, as long as they show the defined characteristics.

Comment: @deceze Strictly speaking, that is true, OK, I agree. I meant more like... is block scope a first class thing, or just a syntax sugar of some sort on top of the old traditional function scope. I am sure people see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, but… where's the distinction? The language specification treats it as first class behaviour. If the implementation behaves that way, where's the difference?

Comment: @deceze As I said, I agree... OK :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But... deep down... how is this done/implemented really? Is there really now in the language a first-class notion of block scope in JS...?

Yes, there is. A new block¹ creates a new [lexical environment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lexical-environments) in the same way that creating a function does (without, obviously, all the other aspects of creating a function). You can see that in the [Evaluation section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of blocks in the spec.

It's a first-class language construct.

---

¹ I originally wrote *"...containing a `let`, `const`, or `class` declaration..."* but the specification doesn't actually make that distinction, though I expect JavaScript engines do (since there's no need for a new environment if there are no lexically-declared bindings).

---

In a comment you've asked:

> What about hoisting? I read that block scoped-variables are hoisted to the top of the block they are defined in... but then also... You get an error if you try to access a block-scoped variable before the line/statement where it is declared in its block? This sounds contradictory, no? If they are hoisted we would not be getting this error but we would be getting undefined. What is the truth here?

In [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119367956) I describe them as *half-hoisted*: The *creation* of the variable (more generally, the "binding") is hoisted to the top of the scope in which its declaration (`let x` or whatever) appears (the block, in this case), but the binding isn't *initialized* until the declaration is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. The time between creation and initialization is called the *Temporal Dead Zone*. You can't use the binding (at all) within the TDZ.

This only applies to `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations. `var` is handled differently in two ways: 1. Obviously, `var` is hoisted to the top of the function (or global) scope, not just block scope. 2. Less obviously, `var` bindings are both created *and* initialized (with the value `undefined`) upon entry to the scope. They're *fully* hoisted. (The *declaration* of them is; any initializer on the `var` statement is actually an assignment, and done when that statement is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code.)

Here's an example:

```js
function foo(n) {
    // `l1` and `l2` don't exist here at all here
    // `v` is created and initialized with `undefined` here, so we can happily
    // do this:
    console.log(`v = ${v}`);
    if (n > 10) {
        // `l1` and `l2` are created here but not initialized; if we tried to
        // use them here, we'd get an error; uncomment this line to see it:
        // console.log(`l1 = ${l1}`);
        console.log("n is > 10");
        var v = "a";  // `v` is assigned the value `"a"` here, replacing the
                      // value `undefined`
        let l1 = "b"; // `l1` is initialized with the value `"b"` here
        console.log(`l1 = ${l1}`);
        let l2;       // `l2` is initialized with the value `undefined `here
        console.log(`l2 = ${l2}`);
        l2 = "c";     // `l2` is assigned the value `"c"` here, replacing the
                      // value `undefined`
        console.log(`l2 = ${l2}`);
    }
}
foo(20);
```

Just for completeness, `function` declarations are also fully-hoisted, but even more so than `var`: The function is actually created and assigned to the binding upon entry to the scope (unlike `var`, which gets the value `undefined`).

---

In a comment you've observed:

> Then... I don't see what's the difference between no hoisting and half-hoisting...

Good point, I didn't explain that. The difference relates to *shadowing* identifiers in the outer scope. Consider:

```
function foo() {
    let a = 1;
    if (/*...*/) {
        console.log(`a = ${a}`);
        let a = 2;
        // ...
    }
}
```

What should the log show?

Sorry, that was a trick question; the log doesn't show anything, because you get an error trying to use `a` there, because the inner `a` declaration *shadows* (hides) the outer `a` declaration, but the inner `a` isn't initialized yet, so you can't use it yet. It's in the TDZ.

It would have been *possible* to make the outer `a` accessible there, or to make the inner `a` accessible there with the value `undefined` (e.g., fully hoisting it like `var`, but just within the block), but both of those have problems the TDZ helps solve. (Specifically: Using the outer `a` would have been confusing for programmers [`a` means one thing at the beginning of the block but something else later?!] and would have meant JavaScript engines had to create new lexical environments all over the place, basically every `let` or `const` or `class` would introduce a new one. And pre-initializing with `undefined` is confusing for programmers, as `var` has shown us over the years...)

Comment: more over, the block is an old language structure (-> labels and `break`).

Comment: @NinaScholz - Right. Blocks are as old as JS; block *scope* is new (to JS) in ES2015. (Well...mostly. The block on `with` statements had aspects of block scope.)

Comment: OK, thanks, that's the answer/confirmation I was looking for.

Comment: One more question, if I may... What about hoisting? I read that block scoped-variables are hoisted to the top of the block they are defined in... but then also... You get an error if you try to access a block-scoped variable before the line/statement where it is declared in its block? This sounds contradictory, no? If they are hoisted we would not be getting this error but we would be getting undefined. What is the truth here?

Comment: Hm... Interesting... Then... I don't see what's the difference between no hoisting and half-hoisting but... OK... Apparently there's some difference if you put it officially in a book. Interesting indeed.

Comment: @peter.petrov - Ah! Good point! I didn't explain that. The difference is *shadowing*. I'll put an example in the answer.

Comment: @peter.petrov - Done now. :-) (BTW: *"officially in a book"* made me laugh. Things in books are often wrong. I'm hoping that's not the case with *my* book, obviously, but... :-D )

Comment: OK :) Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. "It would have been possible to make the outer `a` accessible there, or to make the inner `a` accessible there with the value undefined (e.g. fully hoisting it like `var`, but just within the block)" That's a very good thought. What I am thinking: the former would have been a true mess indeed, I agree. I would have done the latter if it was up to me... if only to keep it consistent with the hoisting behavior of `var` (function-scoped) variables. Developers should be already well-used to that behavior :) given for how many years it has been around.